# Spring Cloud Function - Manual Bean Registration and Loading Configuration Classes

Tags: spring-cloud-function

I am currently using Spring Cloud function 3.07.RELEASE with the AWS Adapter for lambda.

We are using a limited scope Functional Bean registration and understand that this does not include full Spring Boot autoconfiguration. We are okay with this as we value the speed and significant reduction cold start times.

However, we do have configuration classes that we want to utilize and assume that this needs to be done manually. What is the best practice on importing these classes?

We tried searching, but failed to find documentation on the differences in behavior of the limited scope context vs spring boot application context.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly all you need to do is register those configuration classes manually and the rest will be autowired. There was a [little issue with it](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/554) which may or may not affect you. In any event it was fixed and will be available in 3.0.9 release next week.

Comment: Thank you Oleg.We will try the next version and go from there. Regarding pulling in starter dependencies, should those behave as normal or do they also require importing the autoconfiguration classes found in spring.factories?